# Sticky footer with header and content dropping below window

Tags: html, css, sticky, sticky-footer

I have a layout where the footer is a sibling of the header and content, but the footer is dropping below the window height rather than "sticking" correctly at the bottom.

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="content">
  Content
  <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%
}

.header, .footer, .push {
  height: 75px;
}

.content {
  margin-bottom: -75px;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

I've been looking over [different options for sticky footer](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/), and none seem to cover when the header and content are sibling elements with the footer. I'm working with a legacy layout, so I don't have the option of creating a wrapper container for the header and content. How can I get the footer to stay at the bottom without dropping below the window?

Comment: @zgood thanks, that does seem to help.

Comment: I made it into an answer with more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your header and footer are static heights you can do this:

```
min-height: calc(100% - 75px - 75px);
```

I keep them separate (the 75px), so that I know one is for footer and one is for header. And its easier to change in the future if one of the static heights changes.

Also, you will probably want to remove the margin from your `body` to get it to fit correctly and remove the negative margin you have on the footer.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.header, .footer, .push {
  height: 75px;
}

.content {
  min-height: calc(100% - 75px - 75px);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="content">
  Content
  <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3wp9eauj/) of this solution.

Answer (score 0):

add `footer` css with a separate class

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```